# How do I extend React classes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I tried this (note they are really separate files):

```
export default Class Foo extends React.Component {}
export default Class Foo2 extends Foo {}
```

Then React complained I was using a literal object instead of a React class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With ES6:

```
// File Foo.js
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'
class Foo extends React.Component {
  ...
}
export default Foo;


// File Bar.js
import Foo from 'Foo'
class Bar extends Foo {
  ...
}
```

For transpiling that you can use [Babel](https://babeljs.io/), [Browserify](https://github.com/babel/babelify) or [Webpack](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader).

Comment: I'm gonna try this again later. Thought that's what I had done and got an error.

Comment: Yeah I was getting screwed cause I wasn't used to latest ES classes. I had to change getInitialState to this.state = {} in constructor, on top of the conversion above

Comment: Prefer composition over inheritance in that case. You should look into the *Higher Order Component* pattern